# Navigation bar with bottom border move up text if it's selected

Tags: javascript, css, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to create a navigation bar with tabs, each tab should has a bottom border if it's selected.
The problem is that when the border is "active", the text move up and I don't want that.

How can I solve?

Here a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-galileo-g1tps?file=/src/App.js) that reproduce the case. I tried with box-sizing and with overflow hidden but it seems not to work...

I don't like the second example because the border is not inside the gray area

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: you have to put all items border bottom color to *transparent*

for example you can add `border-bottom: 0.5rem solid transparent;` to all your items

Answer (score 0):

You can add "pt2" className to the selected tab.